# What are these two vegetables called?

Tags: food-identification

For bonus points how do I cook the one on the top?
[image]

The bottom one I already cooked but here it is now:
[image]

Comment: The top one is definitely [Kohlrabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohlrabi) and there are lots of fun recipes for that one. Can you cut open the bottom one as it looks like a round zucchini but the colour is a bit off, so I'd like to see the inside as well.

Comment: wonder if it is a Thai eggplant?

Comment: @steve chambers Looks very [similar](https://www.google.com/search?q=Thai+eggplant&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOxPCUhf_bAhXMFzQIHQYAB0wQ_AUICigB&biw=1600&bih=747). The geographic region is mexico.

Comment: I'd think twice about eating the bottom one, from the pictures it looks like it may have gone off.

Answer (score 8):

The top is a kohlrabi. Two approaches I like a lot:

- treat it like a potato. Peel it, cut into chunks, and boil it (and optionally sliced the boiled pieces and fry them in a little butter)
- treat it like cabbage or jicama. Peel it, julienne it raw and toss with grated carrot and whatever you dress coleslaw with (mayo and lemon juice for me)

The bottom could be a very small squash or a round zucchini. You can roast, sautee, or braise (think ratatouille). If it's a zucchini you can also eat it raw.